# How can a server take more than one request from a client without shutting down?

Tags: java, android, json

I have implemented a very simple Java server, which basically listens for all requests on port 8080 and writes them to the console.

My code works fine, once. But for each server restart, it will only take one request.

Server code:

```
public class RunServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int port = 8080;
        final String path = "/android";
        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);     //Create the server to listen for incoming requests on the specified port
            server.createContext(path, new HttpHandler() { //Set a handler for     incoming requests to the specific path
                @Override
                public void handle(HttpExchange arg0) throws IOException {     //This method is called when new requests are incoming
                            InputStreamReader isr = new     InputStreamReader(arg0.getRequestBody(),"utf-8");
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                            String query = br.readLine();

                            System.out.print(query);
                } });           
            server.setExecutor(null); //Default executor. Other executors may be     used to e.g. use a threadpool for handling concurrent incoming requests.
            server.start(); //Start the server.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

I am using this client to post to my server:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.5:8080/android");
    String s;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Building post parameters
        // key and value pair
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "user@gmail.com"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                "Hi, trying Android HTTP post!"));

        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: you should first start working and putting pieces together. This is a forum to solve problems not to do you work.

Comment: I've been trying for quite som time now, but we've never been introduced to this sort of programming, so when i program something, i don't know whether i am even on the right track. My question were more in the line of, if people have en example at hand, or something similar, and they could share it, so i could get a clue as to which direction to go in.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by decomposing the problem. You will need to find (or build) components that can solve these problems:

**Server side**

- Listen for network connections
- Read data from the network stream
- Parse JSON data
- Process JSON into a useful format [optional]
- Store data on disk
- Read data from disk
- Send data back to the client over the network

**Android side**

- Connect to the server over the network
- Send JSON data
- Request data from the server

There are many SO questions related to each of these. If you have a specific question about one of these problems, please post it as a separate question.